# Problems compressing files using Nextflow

Tags: gzip, nextflow

I try to compress files with the suffix '.js' in a Nextflow pipeline.
My problem is that the 'result.tar.gz' archive only contains soft links to the original file and not the actual file.

Does anybody know a answer to that problem?

My example Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

a_ch  = Channel
    .fromPath('a.js')

b_ch = Channel
    .fromPath('b.js')

process testTar {
    publishDir "." ,mode: 'copy' , pattern: "*.tar.gz"

    input:
    path "a.js" from a_ch
    path "b.js" from b_ch

    output:
    path("result.tar.gz") into results_ch

    """
    tar -czvf "result.tar.gz" *.js
    """
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what tar you have, but try adding an `h` in the options, e.g. `-chzvf`, to dereference symbolic links.